# Null safety error showing after checking for null (typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular 12 with nx.

Below is my code

```
if (this.cytograph != null && this.cytograph.removeFullLabelFn != null) {
  this.cytograph.removeFullLabelFn({ target: null, type: 'mouseout' });
}
```

I get errors during compilation.

> error TS2721: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.
> this.cytograph.removeFullLabelFn({ target: null, type: 'mouseout' });

How can I fix this?
I have no idea why I still get an error even if I check `null` values.

Comment: I just see the reason. I changed `removeFullLabelFn = null;` to `removeFullLabelFn: any = null;` then it fixed

Comment: You should not use the `any` type, declare your function properly instead: `(v: theType) => void`